# "clang: error: cannot specify -o when generating multiple output files" fix

Tags: c, clang

I'm trying to compile my C project using clang (I'm on MacOS Monterry) and a Makefile, but I keep getting the same error from clang in the command line:

```
> make
gcc -c src/ji.c src/main.c -o src/ji.o
clang: error: cannot specify -o when generating multiple output files
make: *** [src/ji.o] Error 1
```

These are the only files I have in the project so far:

```
src/main.c
src/ji.c
include/ji.h
```

The Makefile looks like this:

```makefile
cc = gcc
src = $(wildcard src/*.c)
obj = $(src:.c=.o)
exec = ji

$(exec): $(obj)
    $(cc) -Iinclude $< -o build/$@

%.o: %.c
    $(cc) -c $(src) -o $@

clean:
    -rm src/*.o
    -rm ji
```

From YouTube videos I've seen, this should be the ideal Makefile for the project but no matter what I change I get the error.

Comment: You can just remove the entire `%.o: %.c` block. It is both wrong and unnecessary. Wrong because `$(src)` is more  than one file and should instead be `$<`. Unnecessary because it doesn't do anything extra that the implicit rule does not already provide.

Comment: `$(cc) -Iinclude $< -o build/$@` is also wrong for multiple reasons. 1. `-Iinclude` is for compile phase but this rule is linking. 2. `$<` gives only the first pre-requisite wherase you need the all the prerequisites.

Comment: @kaylum Don't we _need_ the `%.o: %.c` rule because that's where we need to put the `-Iinclude`?

Comment: @CraigEstey That's one way to do it but the better way would be to set `CFLAGS` with any include or other build options. The implicit rule is of the form: `$(CC) -c $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS)`

Comment: When you do `clang -c file1.c file2.c -o somename`, Clang doesn't know whether to place `file1.o` or `file2.o` into `somename` — so it complains.  You need to compile a single source file to object file if you're going to use `-o` — or you need to be compiling multiple source files into a single executable (no `-c` option).

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues:

1. `-Iinclude` needs to be on the `%.o: %.c` rule command
2. In `%.o: %.c`, we don't want `$(src)` but rather `$<`
3. We want `patsubst` to get the `.o` list `obj`
4. The `$(exec)` target doesn't match the `-o` option
5. The `clean` doesn't match the placement of the executable

Here's a refactored version (e.g. one way to do this--there are others):

```
cc = gcc
src = $(wildcard src/*.c)
obj = $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(src))
exec = build/ji

$(exec): $(obj)
    mkdir -p build
    $(cc) $^ -o $@

%.o: %.c
    $(cc) -c $< -o $@ -Iinclude

clean:
    rm -f src/*.o
    rm -fr build
```

---

Here's the output of `make`:

```
gcc -c src/ji.c -o src/ji.o -Iinclude
gcc -c src/main.c -o src/main.o -Iinclude
mkdir -p build
gcc src/ji.o src/main.o -o build/ji
```

---

Here's the output of `make clean`:

```
rm -f src/*.o
rm -fr build
```